# Color palettes - RAL to hex or RGB

Tags: color, css, rgb

I'm looking for a way to transform the RAL color palette to hex or RGB so I can use the colors in CSS (all/any of them).

Is there an XML file someone can point me to, or a database somewhere, that's an elegant solution, rather than my scraping the data myself?

(BTW very surprised "hex" and "RAL" aren't tags here...yet)

Comment: Can you add some context - why are you doing this? I have some comments but they are somewhat dependent on what you expect to achieve.

Comment: @e100 - interested to hear your comments.  I'm building a catalog on a website, client wants RAL colors presented as swatches, but consistent with the site's presentation (and without linking outside of the domain).

Comment: BTW, „hex“ is not really a color scheme. It typically used to represent „simple Colors“ in html. It is then a 24bit representation of the sRGyb

Comment: .. of the sRGB colorspace with no Alpha Information. Sometimes if two digits are added it represents rgba with alpha channel (but that’s not used in html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ended up scraping it myself from [RALcolor.com](http://ralcolor.com/).  Here it is in JSON format if someone needs it in the future.

```
{"RAL1000":{"name":"Green beige","hex":"#BEBD7F","rgb":"190-189-127"},"RAL1001":{"name":"Beige","hex":"#C2B078","rgb":"194-176-120"},"RAL1002":{"name":"Sand yellow","hex":"#C6A664","rgb":"198-166-100"},"RAL1003":{"name":"Signal yellow","hex":"#E5BE01","rgb":"229-190-001"},"RAL1004":{"name":"Golden yellow","hex":"#CDA434","rgb":"205-164-052"},"RAL1005":{"name":"Honey yellow","hex":"#A98307","rgb":"169-131-007"},"RAL1006":{"name":"Maize yellow","hex":"#E4A010","rgb":"228-160-016"},"RAL1007":{"name":"Daffodil yellow","hex":"#DC9D00","rgb":"220-156-000"},"RAL1011":{"name":"Brown beige","hex":"#8A6642","rgb":"138-102-066"},"RAL1012":{"name":"Lemon yellow","hex":"#C7B446","rgb":"199-180-070"},"RAL1013":{"name":"Oyster white","hex":"#EAE6CA","rgb":"234-230-202"},"RAL1014":{"name":"Ivory","hex":"#E1CC4F","rgb":"225-204-079"},"RAL1015":{"name":"Light ivory","hex":"#E6D690","rgb":"230-214-144 "},"RAL1016":{"name":"Sulfur yellow","hex":"#EDFF21","rgb":"237-255-033"},"RAL1017":{"name":"Saffron yellow","hex":"#F5D033","rgb":"245-208-051"},"RAL1018":{"name":"Zinc yellow","hex":"#F8F32B","rgb":"248-243-053"},"RAL1019":{"name":"Grey beige","hex":"#9E9764","rgb":"158-151-100"},"RAL1020":{"name":"Olive yellow","hex":"#999950","rgb":"153-153-080"},"RAL1021":{"name":"Rape yellow","hex":"#F3DA0B","rgb":"243-218-011"},"RAL1023":{"name":"Traffic yellow","hex":"#FAD201","rgb":"250-210-001"},"RAL1024":{"name":"Ochre yellow","hex":"#AEA04B","rgb":"174-160-075"},"RAL1026":{"name":"Luminous yellow","hex":"#FFFF00","rgb":"255-255-000"},"RAL1027":{"name":"Curry","hex":"#9D9101","rgb":"157-145-001"},"RAL1028":{"name":"Melon yellow","hex":"#F4A900","rgb":"244--169-000"},"RAL1032":{"name":"Broom yellow","hex":"#D6AE01","rgb":"214-174-001"},"RAL1033":{"name":"Dahlia yellow","hex":"#F3A505","rgb":"243-165-005"},"RAL1034":{"name":"Pastel yellow","hex":"#EFA94A","rgb":"239-169-074"},"RAL1035":{"name":"Pearl beige","hex":"#6A5D4D","rgb":"106-093-077"},"RAL1036":{"name":"Pearl gold","hex":"#705335","rgb":"112-083-053"},"RAL1037":{"name":"Sun yellow","hex":"#F39F18","rgb":"243-159-024"},"RAL2000":{"name":"Yellow orange","hex":"#ED760E","rgb":"237-118-014"},"RAL2001":{"name":"Red orange","hex":"#C93C20","rgb":"201-060-032"},"RAL2002":{"name":"Vermilion","hex":"#CB2821","rgb":"203-040-033"},"RAL2003":{"name":"Pastel orange","hex":"#FF7514","rgb":"255-117-020"},"RAL2004":{"name":"Pure orange","hex":"#F44611","rgb":"244-070-017"},"RAL2005":{"name":"Luminous orange","hex":"#FF2301","rgb":"255-035-001"},"RAL2007":{"name":"Luminous bright orange","hex":"#FFA420","rgb":"255-164-032"},"RAL2008":{"name":"Bright red orange","hex":"#F75E25","rgb":"247-094-037"},"RAL2009":{"name":"Traffic orange","hex":"#F54021","rgb":"245-064-033"},"RAL2010":{"name":"Signal orange","hex":"#D84B20","rgb":"216-075-032"},"RAL2011":{"name":"Deep orange","hex":"#EC7C26","rgb":"236-124-038"},"RAL2012":{"name":"Salmon range","hex":"#E55137","rgb":"235-106-014"},"RAL2013":{"name":"Pearl orange","hex":"#C35831","rgb":"195-088-049"},"RAL3000":{"name":"Flame red","hex":"#AF2B1E","rgb":"175-043-030"},"RAL3001":{"name":"Signal red","hex":"#A52019","rgb":"165-032-025"},"RAL3002":{"name":"Carmine red","hex":"#A2231D","rgb":"162-035-029"},"RAL3003":{"name":"Ruby red","hex":"#9B111E","rgb":"155-017-030"},"RAL3004":{"name":"Purple red","hex":"#75151E","rgb":"117-021-030"},"RAL3005":{"name":"Wine red","hex":"#5E2129","rgb":"094-033-041"},"RAL3007":{"name":"Black red","hex":"#412227","rgb":"065-034-039"},"RAL3009":{"name":"Oxide red","hex":"#642424","rgb":"100-036-036"},"RAL3011":{"name":"Brown red","hex":"#781F19","rgb":"120-031-025"},"RAL3012":{"name":"Beige red","hex":"#C1876B","rgb":""},"RAL3013":{"name":"Tomato red","hex":"#A12312","rgb":"161-035-018"},"RAL3014":{"name":"Antique pink","hex":"#D36E70","rgb":"211-110-112"},"RAL3015":{"name":"Light pink","hex":"#EA899A","rgb":"234-137-154"},"RAL3016":{"name":"Coral red","hex":"#B32821","rgb":"179-040-033"},"RAL3017":{"name":"Rose","hex":"#E63244","rgb":"230-050-068"},"RAL3018":{"name":"Strawberry red","hex":"#D53032","rgb":"213-48-50"},"RAL3020":{"name":"Traffic red","hex":"#CC0605","rgb":"204-006-005"},"RAL3022":{"name":"Salmon pink","hex":"#D95030","rgb":"217-080-048"},"RAL3024":{"name":"Luminous red","hex":"#F80000","rgb":"248-000-000"},"RAL3026":{"name":"Luminousbright red","hex":"#FE0000","rgb":"254-000-000"},"RAL3027":{"name":"Raspberry red","hex":"#C51D34","rgb":"197-029-052"},"RAL3028":{"name":"Pure  red","hex":"#CB3234","rgb":"203-050-052"},"RAL3031":{"name":"Orient red","hex":"#B32428","rgb":"179-036-040"},"RAL3032":{"name":"Pearl ruby red","hex":"#721422","rgb":"114-020-034"},"RAL3033":{"name":"Pearl pink","hex":"#B44C43","rgb":"180-076-067"},"RAL4001":{"name":"Red lilac","hex":"#6D3F5B","rgb":"222-076-138"},"RAL4002":{"name":"Red violet","hex":"#922B3E","rgb":"146-043-062"},"RAL4003":{"name":"Heather violet","hex":"#DE4C8A","rgb":"222-076-138"},"RAL4004":{"name":"Claret violet","hex":"#641C34","rgb":"110-028-052"},"RAL4005":{"name":"Blue lilac","hex":"#6C4675","rgb":"108-070-117"},"RAL4006":{"name":"Traffic purple","hex":"#A03472","rgb":"160-052-114"},"RAL4007":{"name":"Purple violet","hex":"#4A192C","rgb":"074-025-044"},"RAL4008":{"name":"Signal violet","hex":"#924E7D","rgb":"00"},"RAL4009":{"name":"Pastel violet","hex":"#A18594","rgb":"164-125-144"},"RAL4010":{"name":"Telemagenta","hex":"#CF3476","rgb":"215-045-109"},"RAL4011":{"name":"Pearl violet","hex":"#8673A1","rgb":"134-115-161"},"RAL4012":{"name":"Pearl black berry","hex":"#6C6874","rgb":"108-104-129"},"RAL5000":{"name":"Violet blue","hex":"#354D73","rgb":"042-046-075"},"RAL5001":{"name":"Green blue","hex":"#1F3438","rgb":"031-052-056"},"RAL5002":{"name":"Ultramarine blue","hex":"#20214F","rgb":"032-033-079"},"RAL5003":{"name":"Saphire blue","hex":"#1D1E33","rgb":"029-030-051"},"RAL5004":{"name":"Black blue","hex":"#18171C","rgb":"032-033-079"},"RAL5005":{"name":"Signal blue","hex":"#1E2460","rgb":"030-045-110"},"RAL5007":{"name":"Brillant blue","hex":"#3E5F8A","rgb":"062-095-138"},"RAL5008":{"name":"Grey blue","hex":"#26252D","rgb":"038-037-045"},"RAL5009":{"name":"Azure blue","hex":"#025669","rgb":"002-086-105"},"RAL5010":{"name":"Gentian blue","hex":"#0E294B","rgb":"014-041-075"},"RAL5011":{"name":"Steel blue","hex":"#231A24","rgb":"035-026-036"},"RAL5012":{"name":"Light blue","hex":"#3B83BD","rgb":"059-131-189"},"RAL5013":{"name":"Cobalt blue","hex":"#1E213D","rgb":"037-041-074"},"RAL5014":{"name":"Pigeon blue","hex":"#606E8C","rgb":"096-111-140"},"RAL5015":{"name":"Sky blue","hex":"#2271B3","rgb":"034-113-179"},"RAL5017":{"name":"Traffic blue","hex":"#063971","rgb":"006-057-113"},"RAL5018":{"name":"Turquoise blue","hex":"#3F888F","rgb":"063-136-143"},"RAL5019":{"name":"Capri blue","hex":"#1B5583","rgb":"027-085-131"},"RAL5020":{"name":"Ocean blue","hex":"#1D334A","rgb":"029-051-074"},"RAL5021":{"name":"Water blue","hex":"#256D7B","rgb":"037-109-123"},"RAL5022":{"name":"Night blue","hex":"#252850","rgb":"037-040-080"},"RAL5023":{"name":"Distant blue","hex":"#49678D","rgb":"073-103-141"},"RAL5024":{"name":"Pastel blue","hex":"#5D9B9B","rgb":"093-155-155"},"RAL5025":{"name":"Pearl gentian blue","hex":"#2A6478","rgb":"042-100-120"},"RAL5026":{"name":"Pearl night blue","hex":"#102C54","rgb":"016-044-084"},"RAL6000":{"name":"Patina green","hex":"#316650","rgb":"049-102-080"},"RAL6001":{"name":"Emerald green","hex":"#287233","rgb":"040-114-051"},"RAL6002":{"name":"Leaf green","hex":"#2D572C","rgb":"045-087-044"},"RAL6003":{"name":"Olive green","hex":"#424632","rgb":"066-070-050"},"RAL6004":{"name":"Blue green","hex":"#1F3A3D","rgb":"031-058-061"},"RAL6005":{"name":"Moss green","hex":"#2F4538","rgb":"047-069-056"},"RAL6006":{"name":"Grey olive","hex":"#3E3B32","rgb":"062-059-050"},"RAL6007":{"name":"Bottle green","hex":"#343B29","rgb":"052-059-041"},"RAL6008":{"name":"Brown green","hex":"#39352A","rgb":"057-053-042"},"RAL6009":{"name":"Fir green","hex":"#31372B","rgb":"049-055-043"},"RAL6010":{"name":"Grass green","hex":"#35682D","rgb":"053-104-045"},"RAL6011":{"name":"Reseda green","hex":"#587246","rgb":"088-114-070"},"RAL6012":{"name":"Black green","hex":"#343E40","rgb":"052-062-064"},"RAL6013":{"name":"Reed green","hex":"#6C7156","rgb":"108-113-086"},"RAL6014":{"name":"Yellow olive","hex":"#47402E","rgb":"071-064-046"},"RAL6015":{"name":"Black olive","hex":"#3B3C36","rgb":"059-060-054"},"RAL6016":{"name":"Turquoise green","hex":"#1E5945","rgb":"030-089-069"},"RAL6017":{"name":"May green","hex":"#4C9141","rgb":"076-145-065"},"RAL6018":{"name":"Yellow green","hex":"#57A639","rgb":"087-166-057"},"RAL6019":{"name":"Pastel green","hex":"#BDECB6","rgb":"189-236-182"},"RAL6020":{"name":"Chrome green","hex":"#2E3A23","rgb":"046-058-035"},"RAL6021":{"name":"Pale green","hex":"#89AC76","rgb":"137-172-118"},"RAL6022":{"name":"Olive drab","hex":"#25221B","rgb":"037-034-027"},"RAL6024":{"name":"Traffic green","hex":"#308446","rgb":"048-132-070"},"RAL6025":{"name":"Fern green","hex":"#3D642D","rgb":"061-100-045"},"RAL6026":{"name":"Opal green","hex":"#015D52","rgb":"001-093-082"},"RAL6027":{"name":"Light green","hex":"#84C3BE","rgb":"132-195-190"},"RAL6028":{"name":"Pine green","hex":"#2C5545","rgb":"044-085-069"},"RAL6029":{"name":"Mint green","hex":"#20603D","rgb":"032-096-061"},"RAL6032":{"name":"Signal green","hex":"#317F43","rgb":"049-127-067"},"RAL6033":{"name":"Mint turquoise","hex":"#497E76","rgb":"073-126-118"},"RAL6034":{"name":"Pastel turquoise","hex":"#7FB5B5","rgb":"127-181-181"},"RAL6035":{"name":"Pearl green","hex":"#1C542D","rgb":"028-084-045"},"RAL6036":{"name":"Pearl opal green","hex":"#193737","rgb":"022-053-055"},"RAL6037":{"name":"Pure green","hex":"#008F39","rgb":"000-143-057"},"RAL6038":{"name":"Luminous green","hex":"#00BB2D","rgb":"000-187-045"},"RAL7000":{"name":"Squirrel grey","hex":"#78858B","rgb":"120-133-139"},"RAL7001":{"name":"Silver grey","hex":"#8A9597","rgb":"138-149-151"},"RAL7002":{"name":"Olive grey","hex":"#7E7B52","rgb":"126-123-082"},"RAL7003":{"name":"Moss grey","hex":"#6C7059","rgb":"108-112-089"},"RAL7004":{"name":"Signal grey","hex":"#969992","rgb":"150-153-146"},"RAL7005":{"name":"Mouse grey","hex":"#646B63","rgb":"100-107-099"},"RAL7006":{"name":"Beige grey","hex":"#6D6552","rgb":"109-101-082"},"RAL7008":{"name":"Khaki grey","hex":"#6A5F31","rgb":"106-095-049"},"RAL7009":{"name":"Green grey","hex":"#4D5645","rgb":"077-086-069"},"RAL7010":{"name":"Tarpaulin grey","hex":"#4C514A","rgb":"076-081-074"},"RAL7011":{"name":"Iron grey","hex":"#434B4D","rgb":"067-075-077"},"RAL7012":{"name":"Basalt grey","hex":"#4E5754","rgb":"078-087-084"},"RAL7013":{"name":"Brown grey","hex":"#464531","rgb":"070-069-049"},"RAL7015":{"name":"Slate grey","hex":"#434750","rgb":"067-071-080"},"RAL7016":{"name":"Anthracite grey","hex":"#293133","rgb":"041-049-051"},"RAL7021":{"name":"Black grey","hex":"#23282B","rgb":"035-040-043"},"RAL7022":{"name":"Umbra grey","hex":"#332F2C","rgb":"051-047-044"},"RAL7023":{"name":"Concrete grey","hex":"#686C5E","rgb":"104-108-094"},"RAL7024":{"name":"Graphite grey","hex":"#474A51","rgb":"071-074-081"},"RAL7026":{"name":"Granite grey","hex":"#2F353B","rgb":"047-053-059"},"RAL7030":{"name":"Stone grey","hex":"#8B8C7A","rgb":"139-140-122"},"RAL7031":{"name":"Blue grey","hex":"#474B4E","rgb":"071-075-078"},"RAL7032":{"name":"Pebble grey","hex":"#B8B799","rgb":"184-183-153"},"RAL7033":{"name":"Cement grey","hex":"#7D8471","rgb":"125-132-113"},"RAL7034":{"name":"Yellow grey","hex":"#8F8B66","rgb":"143-139-102"},"RAL7035":{"name":"Light grey","hex":"#D7D7D7","rgb":"215-215-215"},"RAL7036":{"name":"Platinum grey","hex":"#7F7679","rgb":"127-118-121"},"RAL7037":{"name":"Dusty grey","hex":"#7D7F7D","rgb":"125-127-120"},"RAL7038":{"name":"Agate grey","hex":"#B5B8B1","rgb":"195-195-195"},"RAL7039":{"name":"Quartz grey","hex":"#6C6960","rgb":"108-105-096"},"RAL7040":{"name":"Window grey","hex":"#9DA1AA","rgb":"157-161-170"},"RAL7042":{"name":"Traffic grey A","hex":"#8D948D","rgb":"141-148-141"},"RAL7043":{"name":"Traffic grey B","hex":"#4E5452","rgb":"078-084-082"},"RAL7044":{"name":"Silk grey","hex":"#CAC4B0","rgb":"202-196-176"},"RAL7045":{"name":"Telegrey 1","hex":"#909090","rgb":"144-144-144"},"RAL7046":{"name":"Telegrey 2","hex":"#82898F","rgb":"130-137-143"},"RAL7047":{"name":"Telegrey 4","hex":"#D0D0D0","rgb":"208-208-208"},"RAL7048":{"name":"Pearl mouse grey","hex":"#898176","rgb":"137-129-118"},"RAL8000":{"name":"Green brown","hex":"#826C34","rgb":"130-108-052"},"RAL8001":{"name":"Ochre brown","hex":"#955F20","rgb":"149-095-032"},"RAL8002":{"name":"Signal brown","hex":"#6C3B2A","rgb":"108-059-042"},"RAL8003":{"name":"Clay brown","hex":"#734222","rgb":"115-066-034"},"RAL8004":{"name":"Copper brown","hex":"#8E402A","rgb":"142-064-042"},"RAL8007":{"name":"Fawn brown","hex":"#59351F","rgb":"089-053-031"},"RAL8008":{"name":"Olive brown","hex":"#6F4F28","rgb":"111-079-040"},"RAL8011":{"name":"Nut brown","hex":"#5B3A29","rgb":"091-058-041"},"RAL8012":{"name":"Red brown","hex":"#592321","rgb":"089-035-033"},"RAL8014":{"name":"Sepia brown","hex":"#382C1E","rgb":"056-044-030"},"RAL8015":{"name":"Chestnut brown","hex":"#633A34","rgb":"099-058-052"},"RAL8016":{"name":"Mahogany brown","hex":"#4C2F27","rgb":"076-047-039"},"RAL8017":{"name":"Chocolate brown","hex":"#45322E","rgb":"069-050-046"},"RAL8019":{"name":"Grey brown","hex":"#403A3A","rgb":"064-058-058"},"RAL8022":{"name":"Black brown","hex":"#212121","rgb":"033-033-033"},"RAL8023":{"name":"Orange brown","hex":"#A65E2E","rgb":"166-094-046"},"RAL8024":{"name":"Beige brown","hex":"#79553D","rgb":"121-085-061"},"RAL8025":{"name":"Pale brown","hex":"#755C48","rgb":"117-092-072"},"RAL8028":{"name":"Terra brown","hex":"#4E3B31","rgb":"078-059-049"},"RAL8029":{"name":"Pearl copper","hex":"#763C28","rgb":"118-060-040"},"RAL9001":{"name":"Cream","hex":"#FDF4E3","rgb":"250-244-227"},"RAL9002":{"name":"Grey white","hex":"#E7EBDA","rgb":"231-235-218"},"RAL9003":{"name":"Signal white","hex":"#F4F4F4","rgb":"244-244-244"},"RAL9004":{"name":"Signal black","hex":"#282828","rgb":"040-040-040"},"RAL9005":{"name":"Jet black","hex":"#0A0A0A","rgb":"010-010-010"},"RAL9006":{"name":"White aluminium","hex":"#A5A5A5","rgb":"165-165-165"},"RAL9007":{"name":"Grey aluminium","hex":"#8F8F8F","rgb":"143-143-143"},"RAL9010":{"name":"Pure white","hex":"#FFFFFF","rgb":"255-255-255"},"RAL9011":{"name":"Graphite black","hex":"#1C1C1C","rgb":"028-028-028"},"RAL9016":{"name":"Traffic white","hex":"#F6F6F6","rgb":"246-246-246"},"RAL9017":{"name":"Traffic black","hex":"#1E1E1E","rgb":"030-030-030"},"RAL9018":{"name":"Papyrus white","hex":"#D7D7D7","rgb":"215-215-215"},"RAL9022":{"name":"Pearl light grey","hex":"#9C9C9C","rgb":"156-156-156"},"RAL9023":{"name":"Pearl dark grey","hex":"#828282","rgb":"130-130-130"}}
```

Of course, if it turns out this information is not free for distribution, my apologies and please delete / flag (I do more coding than graphic design, so I'm not here too often).

Comment: Please note that [ralcolor.com](http://ralcolor.com/) is not affiliated with RAL. The RGB values shown on ralcolor.com differ from values given by RAL. However, RAL claims that the RAL colour collections are protected by copyright.